# MySQL multiple statement order commit

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm using Python to manipulate a MySQL database.  In one of my functions, I have 2 execute statements that must be performed in the order I coded them:

```
database_conn.cursor().execute(sql statement 1)
database_conn.cursor().execute(sql statement 2)
database_conn.commit()
```

Are these two statements guaranteed to be executed and commited in this order?  Thanks.

Comment: computers operate in one of two ways FIFO or LIFO. What makes you think that this order would change. have you tested?

Comment: I tested a few times, but we all no that that's not always a guarantee.  Since I don't know all details of how transactions are handled, it seemed a fair question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a given database session is single-threaded and each execution blocks until its statement completes. So they are guaranteed to apply to the database in the order you execute them.